# Github Issues Partial Match

Tags: regex, search, github

Is it possible to perform a partial word match query for github issues:

For example, if the Issue title is "Missing Polygon", is it possible to query with a syntax similar to:

```
poly* in:title
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is possible using the normal github search with scope limitation.
Have a look [here](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues/#scope-the-search-fields).

e.g. this query will search for the word "error" in the title and body.

```
error in:title,body
```

Comment: Something must have changed on GitHub. I'm no longer seeing partial-word matching on any Issue search. For example, with an issue containing "SQLite" in the title, a search for "SQL" will not return that issue (unless the full-word "SQL" is also present somewhere).

Comment: This doesn't address the *partial match* issue. @patridge is correct, Github issues has apparently no partial match capability.

Answer (score 10):

Partial issue searches are not currently (2016-07-22) possible in Github.

My inquiry to Github's staff:

> Can Github search issues using partial matches? For example: if I try to search for "feat", it will not return issues that contain the word "feature". This is, I have to use the *full word* to obtain a result.

And Github's staff (Robert) response:

> Thanks for getting in touch - search doesn't currently support partial searches, so in your example, you're correct you would have to search for "feature".  Though not the same, we do however do some stemming for plurals - so searching for "features" would find "feature".
>
> But I can definitely see how useful partial searches could be - our search team is working on a number of projects and though we can't make any promises, we'll let them know that partial searches is something you'd like to see.